# Setting up nginx to run more then one nodejs app on https and redirect every http request to https

Tags: nginx, routing, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding, node.js

Nginx is redirecting the `http` to `https` successfully. Both apps are up and running on port `3000` and `3001`. But only the app on port `3000` is accessible in browser by visting `example.com`. Whenever I try `example.com/route` in browser it shows `Cannot GET /route`

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com/$request_uri;
}

server{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/file.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/file.key;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
    }

    location /route {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3001";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: I've had to deploy NodeJS backend recently and walked into this same issue, I believe there's a routing issue with these types of services as they `#` path to navigate and Nginx don't honour that by default specially with reverse-proxy. So I ended up deploying the app from Nginx with [Nginx Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/intro.html) library and dropped reverse-proxy altogether.